# Ambiguous operand size

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

What's wrong with this code? Compiler returns ambiguous operand size for dec in unlock function. But, there is qword keyword (size specifier).

```
class spinlock
{
    qword locked;
public:
    spinlock() : locked(-1)
    { }
    void lock()     __attribute__((noinline));
    void unlock()   __attribute__((noinline));
};

void spinlock::lock()
{
    asm(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "xor rcx, rcx;"
    "loop:;"
    "lock xchg qword [%0], rcx;"
    "test rcx, rcx;"
    "jz loop;"
    ".att_syntax noprefix;"
    : 
    : "r"(&locked)
    : "rcx"
    );
}

void spinlock::unlock()
{
    asm(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "lock dec qword [%0];"
    ".att_syntax noprefix;"
    :
    : "r"(&locked)
    :
    );
}
```

Comment: not sure what the `%0`is (something g++?), but at least with old MASM and TASM the proper syntax was like `QWORD PTR` *operand*.

Comment: you really should give more information. see this C++ FAQ item about **[how to post a question about code that does not work](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html)**. even if it's for another more technical forum, not SO. note especially points **5**, **6** and **7**.

Comment: you are right ... I forgotten ptr keyword ...

Comment: For future readers, **this code is unsafe and slow.**  A pointer operand does not imply that the pointed-to memory is also an operand, and spinning on `xchg` instead of spinning read-only with a `pause` is generally worse.  Also, there's no reason to make these `noinline`: a `"memory"` clobber would make it a full barrier against compile-time reordering.  Unlock doesn't need a `lock` prefix; a release-store of a constant is sufficient.  See [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246263) for a better example.